# Github workflow, job not executed even when job.needs successful

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I have a weird problem with Github workflow. Last job `job_5` is not executed even when job from `needs` (`job_4`) is executed and successful. Can anyone tell my why is that?

Workflow file:

```yaml
name: Test run v2

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job_1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB1

  job_2:
    needs: job_1
    if: false
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB2; exit 1;

  job_3:
    needs: job_1
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB3

  job_4:
    needs: [job_2, job_3]
    if: always()
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB4

  job_5:
    needs: job_4
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
        - run: echo JOB5
```

Workflow visualization looks like this:
[image: workflow]

I can fix that using for example:

```
  job_5:
    needs: job_4
    if: always() && needs.job_4.result == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
        - run: echo JOB5
```

But still why is it not working as expected when `job_4` is a success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the the fact that your `job 4` is dependent on `job 2` and `job 3` and `job 2` failed. So when you put `job 4` as a need for `job 5` it checks not only status of `job 4` but also its dependencies (in this case `job 2` and `job 3`) and since `job 2` failed it failed evaluation needs for `job 5`. What is strange it is that ignores condition `always()` on `job 4`. It could be a bug or designed by purpose. I don't know that. However if you remove `job 2` all went fine

```yaml
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735099/github-workflow-job-not-executed-even-when-job-needs-successful
name: Multiple jobs

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job_1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB1

  job_2:
    needs: job_1
    if: false
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB2; exit 1;

  job_3:
    needs: job_1
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB3

  job_4:
    needs: [job_3]
    if: always()
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - run: echo JOB4

  job_5:
    needs: job_4
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
        - run: echo JOB5
```

[image]

So if this structure is sth you need you should use your workaround.

You can create a topic on [support community](https://github.community/c/code-to-cloud/github-actions/41) as this really can be a bug.

There is open issue on GitHub for this - 
[Job-level "if" condition not evaluated correctly if job in "needs" property is skipped](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/491).

Comment: Question is why skipped jobs are treated as failed? Did you found this in docs somewhere? I looked in docs and could only find that failed job was when canceled or when `exit code != 0`. Can you point to this info in docs or to this information that every job checks every dependent job dependencies?

Comment: No. I haven't found this in docs. I just figure out that modifying your example. However, this is really similar to how it works in [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#succeeded). But obviously this is different tool, but in this area they work pretty the same.

Comment: But [here you have a bug for this 
Job-level "if" condition not evaluated correctly if job in "needs" property is skipped](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/491)

Comment: I've stumbled upon this report once but dismissed it as not related to my problem. But after reading it more it is what is happening in my workflow. Thanks.